# I want to create a KPI that is yes or no depending on 3 other KPIs crossing their threshold

Tags: powerbi

I initially wanted to create alerts that get triggered when three specific kPIs cross their threshold. However, I cannot seem to find the option for that and hence, I have decided to create another KPI in the backend that is a yes or no, depending on whether threshold is crossed for all three.

Answer (score 0):

```
AllThreeKPIs = IF( [KPI 1] > 10 && [KPI 2] > 20 && [KPI 3] > 30, "Yes", "No")
```

Comment: I cannot reference the tables in this syntax

Comment: Update your question to include more detail. Include snips of the visuals you want to track, table names and any other info like slicers, visuals etc...